Як ще можна перекласти "созидательный" окрім як "конструктивний"?
Не можу знайти в українській мові аналог слова "созидательный" який би мене влаштовував, найкраще що я знайшов це "конструктивний", але це не зовсім те.
Ось приклад де я не відчуваю що "конструктивний" підходить.

Він був переконаний що захоплення повинні мати конструктивний (созидательный) характер.

Слово "конструктивний" я відчуваю більше як "створюючий", "будуючий" в той час як "созидательный" мені здається в першу чергу "спокійний", "без шкоди", "творчий", "корисний".

Може творчий? Було б добре, якби ви навели фразу, в якій це слово треба перекласти.

Маленький підсумок: "твірний", "самобутній" і "формуючий", "творильний" - найбільше подобаються


ТВІРНИ́Й

Який утворює або на основі якого утворюється що-небудь.


Також є таке рідковживане слово творильний. Ось приклад вжитку:

Старші Сестри розповідали, наче вона з'явилася на світ з величезної хмари-вихора, породженої спалахом творильної сили Світила.
Віталій Геник (1992). Попередження.


оооо, оце цікаво. Дякую!
